# Is there a way to auto add scrollable lists with item name ,input field and a button under a tab whenever new item is added to the firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase

Whenever i insert a new item to my firebase database I want alist be auto added to the lists under a tab with item name,input field and a button.similarly if i delete the item from db the corresponding list (with item name,input field and button) should also be deleted. Similarly if i update item name, the corresponding list should update the item name.so every time a new item is added, the list should be added under the tab.
So how this is possible ?I want detailed answers please!
Thanks.

Comment: For sure you can. Have tried something so far? If no, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help, as it explains exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.